# is using the $() shortcut in jQuery bad practice?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was recently listening to a podcast which made a comment on using `$()` vs using `jQuery()`. It was stated that every time `$()` was used a new object would be created and when `jQuery()` was used this was not the case. I google'd around but couldn't find anything on this specific topic.

I realize this is not a typical example, but the following is the reason I am interested in the answer to this question.

I have a page that the user will keep loaded in a browser for a whole day (24 hours, or possibly longer) and updates are done to the DOM every ~5 seconds as the result of an AJAX call via jQuery (the AJAX call portion is irrelevant to updating the DOM - the update to the DOM is done using a string of HTML and a call on a jQuery object to `.empty()` and then `.html()`).

Since hearing this, I subsequently switched all of the `$()` calls to `jQuery()` calls, but I would like to know:
Is using `$()` vs using `jQuery()` a bad practice? Is there a negligible difference between the two? Or is it actually noticeable on larger projects?

Comment: The only bad thing I see about it is that $() is hard to search for, so if you ever needed to change scope then it would be difficult

Comment: Using $() like this would create an object every time - `$("#item").html('here'); $("#item").slideUp();`.  Instead if you are using the same element you should chain calls or something like this - `var ele = $("#item"); ele.html('here'); ele.slideUp();`

Comment: What podcast is this so I know to avoid it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, it's not bad practice, and there is no performance difference.

The `$` and `jQuery` identifiers refer to the same function instance.
This is done by the last line of jQuery.js:

```
window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;
```

Comment: @Nate only if `jQuery` also creates a new object in memory everytime

Answer (score 12):

The only problem with using `$()` over `jQuery()` is the possibility that another Javascript framework uses it as well.

Comment: ...and there are ways around this -- check out the documentation on noConflict: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: Also, many other frameworks provide (or at least consider) ways to avoid this conflict.

Answer (score 4):

Nope - take a look at the jQuery source code. $ is just another alias for jQuery - the last line says it all:

```
window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;
```

See here for yourself:
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js

Comment: What if the other library using `$` comes after jQuery?

Answer (score 2):

To me, the goal is to avoid naming collision with other libraries that also use $ as main object, like Prototype, if you want to use both libraries on the same page, or you don't know where your code will be used...

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure it was $() vs jQuery()? Maybe the more salient point is that there are performance hits to doing either, and many new js coders use $() unnecessarily when plain js could do.

It's good practice to avoid creating a jQuery object when you don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

As stated before, the only real problem is getting into conflict with other js frameworks used, therefore i find this is the most handy solution to be still able to use the dollar sign, but have no conflicts and make your code more portable:

```
(function($) { /* some code that uses $ */ })(jQuery)
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries#Referencing_Magic_-_Shortcuts_for_jQuery